# Can I pass HTML tag as prop - React

Tags: reactjs

**I want to do something like this.**

In the parent component

```
<child tag={h1}/>
```

In the child component

```
<this.props.tag />
```

The problem "Unresolved variable or type div" throwing  When i pass one of html components ( tags ) like ( div , h1, ext. )

Answer (score 32, accepted):

UPDATED:

Yes, we can pass HTML tag as a prop. There are several ways based on what you want.

1. Passing tag as a prop

```js
<ChildComponent tag="h1" />
```

And inside child component, we can use the tag as below.

```js
const Child = ({ tag: Tag}) => (
    <Tag>Hello World</Tag>
)
```

2. By setting `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
<Child tags="<h1>Hello world</h1>" />
```

Inside child component:

```
const Child = props => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.tags.outerHTML }}/>
```

> [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) is what you should know about dangerouslySetInnerHTML. In short, this exposes XSS attack.

**This one is not related to passing as a prop. But you might wanna consider**

If you are doing SEO task related (maybe nextjs) and you need to render conditional tag (sometimes h2 and sometimes h3). Then you can do as follow!

3. Conditional Statement

```js
// Parent
const Parent = () => <Child isH3Tag />
```

```js
// Child
const Child = ({ isH3Tag = false, children }) => isH3Tag ? <h3>{children}</h3> : <h2>{children}</h2>;
```

Here is a demo. https://codesandbox.io/s/8x65l707yj

Comment: @Si8 Like how? if you are saying `const h1 =' h1'` and you wanna pass it. use the first method. Otherwise, share me the brief explanation with code.

Comment: how can i define a default tag in method 1?

Comment: you can just do like `const Child = ({ tag: Tag = yourTag }) => {}`.

Answer (score 4):

JSX expressions must start with a cap, for example `<Elment />`

In your case, when you want to pass tag names, use `createElement`:

```
<div>
  {React.createElement(this.props.tag, {children: <content>, prop1: <v1>, ...})}
<div>
```

Another alternative will be to use [`recompose#componentFromProp`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#componentfromprop)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `tag` as children, from parent Component like this:
In the parent component:

```
<Child> <h1></h1> </Child>
```

In the child component you can access like:

```
 render() {
    return (
       {this.props.children}
    )
}
```